# How do I keep a WPF window from freezing during a GUI update?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, inotifypropertychanged, freeze, bindinglist

I have a datagrid with 1000 rows.  The ItemsSource is a CollectionViewSource.  The source for my CollectionViewSource is a BindingList containing objects I've called RowTypes.  My RowType object implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  One property of every RowType changes about every two seconds.  This means that the values in one of the columns of my datagrid change every two seconds.

My problem is that this update effects the user experience.  This update takes about a second during which the user cannot do anything with the GUI.  If this update happens while the user is scrolling through the records of the datagrid, the scrolling will stop (freeze), and then jump ahead a second later.  It's distracting.

Is there a way to keep my window from freezing while updating performing this update?

Comment: How do you fit 1000 rows on the screen? Why not just display and update what you are actually seeing? The problem is you are doing to much that might not be necessary. Lookup Virtualization and maybe read about BackgroundWorker. To stop your window from freezing you must reduce the load on the main thread.

Comment: I am using virtualization (see my other comment). I have a background thread running that updates with stock market information in realtime. I take that market data, run some calculations, update some fields in my business objects, and call the PropertyChangedEventHandler event from INotifyPropertyChanged.  The datagrid knows what to do at this point. This process doesn't use a BackgroundWorker specifically, but it does use a background thread.

Comment: I would look at the CollectionViewSource.  Is it raising a CollectionChanged event that is causing the whole collection to refresh?  That would explain a 1 second pause.   Can you bind to a List or ObservableCollection.  And ListView GridView is faster than DataGrid.

Comment: I'm having trouble putting together a sample project that exhibits the behavior I described above.  My sample project works as I'd expect.  I'll have to dig through my code to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the read operation in separate thread (not UI thread). WPF will perfectly change scalar property on the view. You can easy start the new task:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        // This method is heavy call - to the DataBase or to the WebService
        ReadData(); 
        // In this method, do the updates of the properties of 
        // your RowType collection. You can do it in previous method.
        UpdateData();
     }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // you can log the errors which occurs during data updating
        LogError(e); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that virtualization is on for your DataGrid. With that on, it should only actually update what is shown on the screen, not all 1000 rows. That shouldn't take a full second unless you've got a crazy number of rows on there I suppose.

Comment: I set EnableRowVirtualization and VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing to true.  I also set VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode to both "Recycling" and "Standard".  I am still seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `DeferRefresh()`?

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(RowTypesList);
using (view.DeferRefresh())
{
    // perform updates here
}
```